# How can I determine which type of database is this?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, delphi, firebird

I have a desktop software with a folder called Data. In this folder, I have many files called File001.app, File002.app, T1.app, Z3.app, etc...

When I try to open any of them, they all seem to be in binary format.

The application in written in Delphi.

So how can I know which type of of database is used (Firebird, MySQL, ?)

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to tell. Maybe post the first few characters from the file, maybe somebody recognizes the header

Comment: The most simple will be to put archive with files somewhere and put here a link to the archive. So, after checking archive probably you will get more useful answers.

Comment: I doubt it is Firebird or Interbase. They work with .fdb and .gdb extensions respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try running `strings` against those files and seeing whether there are any clues in the output.

`strings`  was originally [a neat Linux utility](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_strings.htm) but if you are running on Windows (seems a reasonable guess) then you should download the SysInternals implemenation.  [Find it here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897439)

Answer (score 1):

look into the application's code and see the connection string. without application's code, or config files(if exists) there is hard to know the database type. If the code is unavailable the vendor's product should tell you database type.

best regards,

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/app

This sounds like a custom file format to me, doesn't look like anything to do with MySQL or Delphi (not directly et least) and I don't think they have anything to do with Firebird either. I know little about Oracle, but they don't ring any bells. Do you have access to the source code?

Answer (score 0):

As Pekka said, hard to say. But maybe it's the [FoxPro file](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/app) which are stored in dBase file format, but this is not sure.

Comment: IIRC, The App files used by Foxpro are compiled applications, or in some cases they may be custom functions used by indexes (like a primitive stored function). Foxpro tables have a .dbf extension, with an associated .cdx (compressed index) index file.